# subclassing ctypes pointers - how does this code work, and how do I override it?

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm working with the `pylibtiff` library (hosted [here](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/)) and I'm trying to extend `class TIFF(ctypes.c_void_p)`. I'm having trouble with the following method:

```py
# lib has been loaded with the path to libtiff.so, or equivalent
libtiff = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib)

class TIFF(ctypes.c_void_p):
    @classmethod
    def open(cls, filename, mode='r'):
        """ Open tiff file as TIFF.
        """
        tiff = libtiff.TIFFOpen(filename, mode)
        if tiff.value is None:
            raise TypeError ('Failed to open file '+`filename`)
        return tiff
```

(full class [here](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/source/browse/trunk/libtiff/libtiff_ctypes.py#343))

Now, the expected use pattern here is that we open a file and receive a `class TIFF` instance, like this:

```py
import libtiff
t = libtiff.TIFF.open('myfile.tiff')

# e.g. grab a numpy array of the data:
arr = t.read_image()
```

What is this magic? How is the C variable from libtiff [typed as a](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/man/TIFFOpen.3tiff.html) `TIFF*` arriving back in pythonland and automagically becoming a `class TIFF` instance? presumably this has something to do with the subclassing of `ctypes.c_void_p`

I ask because I am trying to override a method on `class TIFF`:

```py
import libtiff
class TIFFdifferent(libtiff.TIFF):
    def read_image(self, verbose=False, different=False):
        if not different:
            return libtiff.TIFF.read_image(self, verbose)

        # my different code ...
```

however, when I try to create a `class TIFFdifferent` instance, I get a `class TIFF` instead:

```
In [3]: t = libtiffdifferent.TIFFdifferent.open('file.tiff')

In [4]: arr = t.read_image(different=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-8bdc24ec874c> in <module>()
----> 1 arr = t.read_image(different=True)

TypeError: read_image() got an unexpected keyword argument 'different'

In [5]: t.read_image?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<bound method TIFF.read_image of <TIFF object at 0x10b67df80>>
File:       /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/libtiff/libtiff_ctypes.py
Definition: t.read_image(self, verbose=False)
Docstring:
Read image from TIFF and return it as an array.


In [6]: t
Out[6]: <TIFF object at 0x10b67df80>
```

So, what I need to do is to override `open` as well - which I don't know how to do without understanding the magic transformation from C `TIFF*` to python `class TIFF` instance, without a constructor, cast or anything else explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is at line 1041 of [libtiff_ctypes.py](http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/source/browse/trunk/libtiff/libtiff_ctypes.py):

```
libtiff.TIFFOpen.restype = TIFF
```

As described in [15.17.1.8 Return types](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#return-types) in the `ctypes` docs, you don't have to use a `ctypes` type as the result type; you can specify any Python callable—typically either a function, which will validate the real C return value to raise an exception, or a class, which will take the real C return value as its constructor argument.

You may notice that the `TIFF` class doesn't define an `__init__` method. This is where the inheritance from `c_void_p` comes in: You can construct a `c_void_p` from a pointer; therefore, if you have a subclass of `c_void_p`, and it doesn't need to do any other initialization, it can just rely on the base-class construction to take care of it.

> So, what I need to do is to override open as well - which I don't know how to do without understanding the magic transformation from C `TIFF*` to python class `TIFF` instance, without a constructor, cast or anything else explicit.

Well, you obviously could just do an explicit construction call in your override, even if the original version doesn't do it:

```
def myopen(*args):
    tiffpointer = libtiff.cfunc(*args)
    return TIFF(tiffpointer)
```

But you'd only want to do this if you can't just define `libtiff.cfunc.restype` (e.g., because some other code in `pylibtiff` relies on the fact that it return something different).

Anyway, I'm not sure this is what you actually want to do. What you're trying to do is write something like this:

```
class TIFFDifferent(TIFF):
    …
    @classmethod
    def open(cls, filename, mode='r'):
        tiff = libtiff.TIFFOpen(filename, mode)
        if tiff.value is None:
            raise TypeError ('Failed to open file '+`filename`)
        return cls(tiff)
```

That works, without you having to understand the magic behind `restype` at all. Unless you're worried about the cost of constructing a short-lived temporary `TIFF` object (which, as you've seen, has no members and no constructor code beyond those of a `c_void_p`), isn't this simple enough?

One more possibility, which I wouldn't normally suggest, and probably isn't appropriate here, but might be: If `pylibtiff` is designed in such a way that overriding its behavior via subclasses is hard to do, you can either (a) fork the code and use your own version, or (b) monkeypatch it at runtime. As suggested in your own comment, something like this:

```
class TIFFDifferent(TIFF):
    …
    @classmethod
    def open(cls, filename, mode='r'):
        stash = libtiff.TIFFOpen.restype
        libtiff.TIFFOpen.restype = cls
        tiff = libtiff.TIFFOpen(filename, mode)
        libtiff.TIFFOpen.restype = stash
        if tiff.value is None:
            raise TypeError ('Failed to open file '+`filename`)
        return tiff
```

You'd want to wrap the stashing up in a `contextmanager` (or use a `try:`/`finally:`), if your constructor could ever possibly throw an exception; otherwise you'll leave the `restype` patched.

Comment: The explicit call in `TIFFDifferent.open` explains all I need, I think. The typing of return values is interesting - thanks! :)

Comment: @tehwalrus: While you're at it, take a look at the `argtypes` too. Until I learned this feature of `ctypes`, my code had more explicit casts than actual code.

Comment: quick note; you may wish to change the answer as at the moment it doesn't work; the resultant object can't properly run the original `TIFF` functions, and occasionally throws segfaults when you try. If you monkey-patch `TIFFOpen.restype` by temporarily reassigning it to `TIFFdifferent`, calling it, and switching back, you get a functioning object. You'll also need to return `tiff`, not `tiff.value`, in the override of `open`! :)